# VBScript debugger implementation - How to get an IProcessDebugManager object on 64-bit Windows?

Tags: delphi, debugging, vbscript

I have been using VBScript via Microsoft's ActiveScript technology for some time, and decided I would like to have a go at implementing the debugger interfaces so I could set breakpoints in the code.

On the latest releases on Windows 10, this seems quite a task as Microsoft has decided to remove the Process Debug Manager (`pdm.dll`) from general release. On general searches, it appears the file is still there, but it doesn't get registered, so the interfaces are not generally available.

I found articles that show how to install (the free) Visual Studio remote tools which does register the PDM, but I'm still having problems.

The example code shows how to get the `IProcessDebugManager` object using the following code.

Note: This is Delphi code so the syntax is fine.

```pascal
hRes := CoCreateInstance(CLSID_ProcessDebugManager,
                              Nil,
                              CLSCTX_ALL,
                              IID_ProcessDebugManager,
                              m_processDebugManager);
```

This fails with an "unknown interface" error on both 32-bit and 64-bit platforms.

Another example shows this code:

```pascal
hres := CoGetClassObject(CLSID_ProcessDebugManager, CLSCTX_INPROC_SERVER,
    Nil, IID_IClassFactory, pcf);
hres := pcf.CreateInstance(nil, IID_ProcessDebugManager, ppdm);
```

This works, but only on 32-bit Windows, 64-bit Windows reports "unknown interface" again.

Actually, the first line `CoGetClassObject()` loads the correct 64-bit version of `pdm.dll`, but the `CreateInstance()` fails to get the `IProcessDebugManager` object (`ppdm`).

Further inspection shows that the `IID_ProcessDebugManager` GUID value, although defined in the Active debug header file, is not defined in the Registry at all, so how does the 32-bit version of this code work, but not the 64-bit version?

Comment: Interesting q.  Do you have a link for "MS has decided to remove ..."?

Comment: @MartynA https://community.sparxsystems.com/community-resources/1046-the-challenge-with-script-debugging-microsoft-process-debug-engine-within-enterprise-architect

Comment: The MIDL interface ID for ProcessDebugManager is different between 64-bit (56b9fc1c-63a9-4cc1-ac21-087d69a17fab) vs. 32-bit (51973C2f-CB0C-11d0-B5C9-00A0244A0E7A).  See if [this article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/dsnotes/iprocessdebugmanager) and [header file](https://github.com/citizenmatt/SimpleActiveScriptHost/blob/master/src/SimpleActiveScriptHost/activdbg.h) help any.

Comment: @leeharvey1 Thanks, that did it. Seems because I am using Delphi, the transcribed header file from the C style .h file to pascal is very old and didn't have the 64 bit IID's. I have manually updated the delphi header file with the WIN64 conditional definitions and seems to work now. Even the CoCreateInstance is working.